# Embedded Fonts Loading Locally but not on Server

Tags: css, fonts, embed

I am trying to embed fonts on my site using the following code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MuseoSans-100';
    src: url('../fonts/MuseoSans-100.html');
    src: url('../fonts/MuseoSans-100d41d.html?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/MuseoSans-101.html') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/MuseoSans-102.html') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/MuseoSans-100.svg#MuseoSans-100') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

However, the fonts are not rendered on the web server, as they are on my local machine.

URL is: http://yakityshmakity.com/careers.html

Comment: Check the permissions folder

Comment: fonts folder and all child objects have been set to 755. The problem ensues.

Comment: Why are they html extensions?

Comment: Wow. Thank you for catching that... Issue resolved.